# error with recaptcha in firebase auth with email and password in android(kotlin)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am getting this warning:

> Creating user with <email> with empty reCAPTCHA token

It is assumed that the recaptcha is only used when registering with the phone, the documentation does not mention that it needs to be recaptcha using the email and password.

Do you have any idea to fix this? I know that is just like a warning, but its weird.

```
package com.integriapp.encuestamovilidad

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.firebase.Firebase
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.auth


class AuthActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth)
        auth = Firebase.auth
        auth.setLanguageCode("es")


        setup()
    }
    fun setup(){
        title = "Autenticación"
        val signUpBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.signUpBtn)
        val loginBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.loginBtn)
        val emailTxt = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.emailTxt)
        val passwordTxt = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.passwordTxt)

        signUpBtn.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("EncuestaMovilidad", "setOnClickListener")
            val email = emailTxt.text.toString()
            val password = passwordTxt.text.toString()

            if (email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
                Log.d("EncuestaMovilidad", "email and password empty")
                return@setOnClickListener
            }

            // Crear un nuevo usuario con las credenciales
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        Log.d("EncuestaMovilidad", "SUCCESS")
                        // Navegar a la siguiente actividad o realizar acciones
                        // tras el registro exitoso
                        val uid = Firebase.auth.currentUser?.uid
                        Log.d("EncuestaMovilidad", "uid: $uid")
                        showHome(task.result.user?.email.toString(), ProviderType.BASIC)
                    } else {
                        val exception = task.exception
                        showErrorAlert("${exception?.message}")
                        Log.e("EncuestaMovilidad", "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.exception)
                    }
                }
        }

        loginBtn.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("EncuestaMovilidad", "setOnClickListener")
            val email = emailTxt.text.toString()
            val password = passwordTxt.text.toString()

            if (email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
                Log.d("EncuestaMovilidad", "email and password empty")
                return@setOnClickListener
            }

            // Iniciar sesión con las credenciales del usuario
            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        Log.d("EncuestaMovilidad", "SUCCESS")

                        val uid = Firebase.auth.currentUser?.uid
                        Log.d("EncuestaMovilidad", "uid: $uid")
                        showHome(task.result.user?.email.toString(), ProviderType.BASIC)
                    } else {
                        val exception = task.exception
                        showErrorAlert("${exception?.message}")
                        Log.e("EncuestaMovilidad", "signInWithEmail:failure", exception)
                    }
                }
        }

    }
    private fun showErrorAlert(msj: String) {
        try {
            val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            builder
                .setTitle("Error")
                .setMessage(msj)
                .setPositiveButton("Aceptar",null)

            val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
            dialog.show()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("AlertDialog", "Error al mostrar el diálogo de alerta:", e)
        }
    }

    private fun showHome(email: String, provider: ProviderType){
        val homeIntent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra("Email", email)
            putExtra("Provider", provider.toString())
        }
        startActivity(homeIntent)
    }
}
```